# Setting fonts in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Is there a way to set font properties in the firemonkey style editor?

I tried both using a custom style and changing the default style of a TButton.
Each of these layouts have a child TText component which is named text. If I try to change the  font settings (e.g. change the bold flag) it looks okay in the designer, but in the form designer as well as at runtime, nothing changes.

Is there also a way to define a default font for all TTextControls? In vcl there is a parentfont property which is not available in Firemonkey. After a closer look to the components code, I think it should be possible by defining the text layout for a TTextControl in the stylebook. But this component is not registered in the component palette.

**Update:** TMenuItem does not apply font settings at all. At the moment it can only be done at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in XE 2 Update Pack 1. Try downloading the new version. You can now set Font styles.